# Why my function.php file in theme delete automatically?

Tags: themes

I was using electro theme. and that was going fine I add some code for woocommerce order cancellation in the function.php file of the theme. after that, my site shows an error that "There has been a critical error on your website.".
when I checked my Cpanel... I found that the function.php file of my theme is missing. I have the site on the localhost and that's is going well. I uploaded function.php file from my localhost theme into the Cpanel, my site runs perfectly but for just 7-10 sec.. after that, it is showing the same error and when I check Cpanel I found that functiono.php is missing again..
I uploaded it again but that got delete again..
I uploaded the whole theme again but got the same issue.. then I uploaded the whole wp-content folder but still the same issue that function.php got delete automatically. then I uploaded the whole site from the localhost and connect it with the database but still, I got the same error..
I set debug to true and I got these errors you can see in screenshot[image]

kindly help me in solving this issue

Comment: Are you saying the code inside the ‘functions.php’ file gets deleted, or the whole file is removed? It sounds like you need to tell this to your hosting providers.

Comment: The error message says you've uploaded the functions.php to `wp-includes/`, not to your theme directory.

Comment: @OmerViews whole file is removed ...

Comment: @fuxia I uploaded this file in theme directory.. in wp-content/themes/electro(my theme)/
 but the file got delete automatically

Comment: Can you upload it with ownership or permissions so the user WordPress is running as can't delete it? To work out whether it's something in your site e.g. some malicious code you've picked up that's doing this. (Probably accidentally, i.e. failing to replicate itself into your theme, rather than deliberately to break things.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this  error was due to the server.. server marked it as spam.. thats why deleting it immediately..